# field to identify a group has a certain value or not in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, Table 1 with 2 columns.

[image: Table1]

My result table should look like

[image].

Representing the presence of a certain value in the group. The table1 is very huge, I don't want to use any cursor or loops. Please suggest me a better way to do it in SQL

Comment: Where does the "A" and "B" come from?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the image now. It should be a bit representing the presence of C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional logic.  Here is one approach:

```
select column1,
       (case when sum(case when column2 = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 1
        end) as has_c,
       (case when sum(case when column2 = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
             then 1
        end) as does_not_have_c,
from table1 t1
group by column1;
```

Or more simply as:

```
select column1,
       max(case when column2 = 'C' then 1 end) as has_c,
       min(case when column2 = 'C' then 0 else 1 end) as does_not_have_c,
from table1 t1
group by column1
```

Comment: Super. Nice solution. Thanks

Comment: Should be `min(case when column2 = 'C' then 0 else 1 end) as does_not_have_c` in the 2nd part